# Change "style.display" property in another php file which is called by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to change style.display property of div element in another php file which is called by ajax when i click on link (in index.php).Is it possible?

index.php code:

```
<div id="list">
            <h2 id="cat_price" style="color:#f5c658">Price Category</h2>
             <ul class="ul1">
            <?php
            $sql="select * from category";
            $execute=mysql_query($sql);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){ ?> 
            <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:show(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo $row['category'] ; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="waxing">

            </div>
```

another php file code where i want to execute script code:

```
                <?php
            include 'admin/connect.php' ;
            $id=$_REQUEST['did'];
            echo "<script>alert('$id');</script>" ;
            if(isset($_REQUEST['did']))
            {
                $id=$_REQUEST['did'];
                $sql="select * from midcat where cid=$id";
                $execute=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($execute)>0){
                    $display="<h2 style='color:#f5c658'>Price Category Waxing</h2>";
                    $display.="<ul class='ul1'>";
                    echo "<script> document.getElementById('list').style.display='none';</script>";
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){
                    $display.="<li> <a href='#'>$row[midcat]</a></li>"; 
                    }
                    $display.="<li><a href='#' onclick='javascript:back()'>Back</a></li>" ;
                    $display.="</ul>";
                    echo $display;
                }

            }
            ?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: its not work? when i click on link, result is display under the div element which have list id...